# Error when trying to open csv in google colab; Jupyter works well

Tags: dataframe, csv, validation, error-handling, jupyter

I can not read this csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3lCw_8Uad_OzHCjvLeYRvamXR74UPbW/view

I've downloaded it and now I am trying to read it using read_csv function.

1. `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv")` gets `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 121535`
2. then I try to do `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` and I get `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6`
3. then I try `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep='\t')`. now it does not give en error, but I get one mixed column "FullDescription,SalaryNormalized" but it should be two different columns with different values - FullDescription and SalaryNormalized... So it does not parse the comma
4. but when I try `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep=',')` I get error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6`

meanwhile, everything works fine in Jupyter Lab just with simple `pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv")`... Unfortunately, I need to use Colab because of GPU, please help me out how I can open this csv!

Comment: 'I try dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep='\t')' .... 'So it does not parse the comma'. It shouldn't parse the comma because you set the separator as tab. If that seems to work, then why not replace that comma with a tab? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) under 'Help others reproduce the problem' it talks about 'How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.' You have supplied much more than a toy dataset. You can probably track down the offending issue yourself by chunking this CSV file.